# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0] while using RestTemplate

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception, resttemplate

I am running a program that will generate some load against a url and further consume the same URL using RestTemplate.

The url that I am hitting will return me a simple string **Hello World** as the response.

Below is the program that will generate the load against the url.

```
public class ShellbareboneLnP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // create thread pool with given size
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

            // queue some tasks
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun * 60 * 1000);

            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
                service.submit(new ShellBareboneTask(endTime));
            }

            service.shutdown();
            service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.warn("Threw a Interrupted Exception in" + CNAME + ".ShellbareboneLnP: boss told me to stop...Not my fault!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn("Threw a Exception in" + CNAME + e);
        } finally {
        }
    }
}


class ShellBareboneTask implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ShellBareboneTask.class.getName());
    public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> exceptionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();
    private final long endTime;


    /**
     * Constructor to pass the values
     * 
     * @param durationOfRun
     */
    public ShellBareboneTask(long endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {

                PerformanceTimer timer = PerformanceTimer.getInstance();
                restTemplate.getForObject("some_url", String.class);
                timer.getDuration();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handleException(e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause().toString() : e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And every time, I am getting the below exception after some time when the program is running. I am not sure what is causing these exceptions. Can anyone help me here?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:426)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
16:04:20,889 ERROR ShellBareboneTask:300 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:426)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
16:04:22,248 ERROR ShellBareboneTask:300 - java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:779)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:47)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    ... 9 more
16:04:24,955 ERROR ShellBareboneTask:300 - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
16:04:24,955 ERROR ShellBareboneTask:300 - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
16:04:24,955 ERROR ShellBareboneTask:300 - java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
16:04:24,955 ERROR ShellBareboneTask:300 - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:269)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:328)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:700)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:779)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:47)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:269)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:328)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:700)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:779)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:47)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    ... 9 more

    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:269)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:328)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:700)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:779)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:47)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    ... 9 more
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:779)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:47)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    ... 9 more
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    ... 9 more
16:04:27,617 ERROR ShellBareboneTask:300 - java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
16:04:27,618 ERROR ShellBareboneTask:300 - java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:779)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:47)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    ... 9 more
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:779)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:47)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    ... 9 more
16:04:39,469 ERROR ShellBareboneTask:300 - java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
    at com.hostdomain.market.shell.barebone.lnp.ShellBareboneTask.run(ShellbareboneLnP.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:779)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:645)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:47)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching constant for [0]
>       at org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:426)

the exception message indicates your server side code generated a response with status code: 0 which is invalid.

can you post your server side code?

Comment: Hi @Septem, why resttemplate is not throwing UnknownHttpStatusCodeException but java.lang.IllegalArgumentException? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while working on Spring version 3, after upgrading to 4.2.2 it got resolved.

Comment: I had this problem on 4.2.1, saw your post, updated to 4.2.2 and now it works. Strange that all my other colleagues didn't had that exact same problem with 4.2.1 though.

Answer (score -2):

I recently had a similar problem.

I've found a solution by changing my **ClientHttpRequest** to **HttpComponentsClient**.

Here's what I've done:

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

Hope it helps